# Error is using absolute difference in dplyr package?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this.

```
df <- data.frame(Year = c(2016,2017,2016,2017),
                 Month = c(1,2,1,2),
                 valueA = c(40,29,25,22),
                 valueB = c(40,36,31,30))
```

I wish to calculate the difference by grouping the columns by year and month.

```
abs(aggregate(.~ Year + Month, df, diff))
#  Year Month valueA valueB
#1 2016     1     15      9
#2 2017     2      7      6
```

The same thing if I am trying in `dplyr` package, it is not working.

```
 library(dplyr)
    df %>% group_by(Year, Month) %>% summarise_all(abs(diff))
    #Error in abs(diff) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

On the other hand, if I remove `abs` function, it works.

```
df %>% group_by(Year, Month) %>% summarise_all((diff))
 

    #Year Month valueA valueB
     # <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
    #1  2016     1    -15     -9
    #2  2017     2     -7     -6
```

Any idea as to why the error is coming and the how can desired output be achieved from `dplyr` package?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply one function you can simply pass `summarise` the function name. However, if you want to apply a composite function you have to be a bit more explicit. Try this:

```r
df <- data.frame(Year = c(2016,2017,2016,2017),
                 Month = c(1,2,1,2),
                 valueA = c(40,29,25,22),
                 valueB = c(40,36,31,30))

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Year, Month) %>% summarise_all(~ abs(diff(.x)))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Groups:   Year [2]
#>    Year Month valueA valueB
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1  2016     1     15      9
#> 2  2017     2      7      6
```

Comment: What does `~` and `(.x)` in the `summarise_all` formula perform?

Comment: @Silent_bliss For convenience dplyr allows to write (anonymous) function using formula notation, i.e. `~ abs(diff(.x))` is the same as `function(x) abs(diff(x))`. So in some sense `~` means `function`. However, when using the formula notation we have to name the argument `.x` or `.`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to calculate absolute values after `summarise_all`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Year, Month) %>%
  summarise_all(diff) %>% 
  mutate_all(abs)
```